# jmeter add directory or jar to class path from relative path

Tags: jmeter

I want to use relative path for TestPlan's 'Add directory or jar to classpath' item.

because the library what I want to use is different from plan( by plan,
so I want to couppling the library to plan, and 'set the directory for jar file' as relative path from plan file.

for example.

```
my/A/plan/A.plan
my/A/libs/some_jar_for_A_plan.jar
```

and set 'Add directory or jar to classpath' as

```
../libs # not works
```

but it looks like it cannot find the jar file.
of course, when I use is as canonical path, it works.

```
my/A/libs/ # works
```

isn't there any method for set library path as relative for plan?
(like csv data set config file path!)

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html)

Just in case, you also can add your `libs` folder to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) by setting `user.classpath` JMeter Property, it can be done:

1. Via `-J` command-line argument:

   ```
   jmeter -Juser.classpath=../libs
   ```
2. By adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   user.classpath=../libs
   ```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)